# Using Folium and Timestampgeojson to display polygons with a time-slider issues

Tags: python, visualization, folium

I am having issues with Folium and using Timestampedgeojson. I have the following dataframe structure below. I am trying to display this data with Folium and a time slider to be used on the date field :

```
    Date        Geometry
0   2016-03-09  POLYGON ((10.00000 25.00000, 10.00000 25.00000, 10.00000 26.00000, 12.00000 26.00000, 18.00000 25.00000, 17.00000 25.00000))
```

I am not sure how to format the dataframe to be read in as a valid JSON into Timestampedgeojson. I tried the following below which does not work. I have been stuck on this issue for a while looking at various tutorials as well.

```
def create_geojson_features(df):

    features = []  

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        features = []
        feature = {
            'type': 'Features',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'MultiPolygon',
                'coordinates':(row['Geometry'])
            },
            'properties': {
                'times':pd.to_datetime(row['Date']),
            }}

        features.append(feature)
        return features

df1 = create_geojson_features(df)

world_map = folium.Map(location=[10,0],tiles="cartodbposition",zoom_start=2,max_zoom=6,min_zoom=3)

TimestampedGeoJson(
          df1,
          period='P1D',
          add_last_point=True,
          auto_play=False,
          loop=False,
          max_speed=1,
          loop_button=True,
          date_options='YYYY-MM-DD',
          time_slider_drag_update=True
         ).add_to(world_map)
```

Comment: Isn't the time unit we are dealing with here the epochal second? I judged it from the [official reference](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html) and [this sample page](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/TimeSliderChoropleth.ipynb).

Comment: I think the time and geometry need to be formatted, but not sure what to do here.

Comment: Have you checked the last sample page? It looks like you are tying the date, color, and opacity data frames to geoJson. I should mention that I don't have a lot of experience with this.

Comment: so the dates will work if I extract them out to a list then pass them but the coordinates are an issue, I do not how to format the coordinates in such a way that it can displayed via timestampedgeojson

Comment: something like this works, but how would I get the coordinates in such a format to pass it to the coordinates field?        
`
 list_dates = gdf[‘Date’].tolist()   

polygon = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'MultiPolygon',
        'coordinates': [((
                   [[10.0, 25.0], [10.0, 25.0], [10.0, 26.0], [12.0, 26.0], [18.0, 25.0], [17.0, 25.0]]
        ),)],
        },
        'properties': {
            'style': {
                'color': 'blue',
            },
            'times':  list_dates
        }
    }     
`

Comment: In another [sample code](https://geohackweek.github.io/ghw2018_web_portal_inlandwater_co2/InteractiveTimeSeries.html#Map-Showing-Levels-of-CO2-Concentration-Measured-at-Different-Locations-Over-Time), the slider side has geojson, color and transparency data for each day. In the other sample code, the slider side has geojson and data for color and transparency by day, and the choropleth side has geojson, data, and columns associated with it.

Comment: How to use polygon coordinates with the TimestampedGeoJson API is the main question

Comment: With point data this all works and have tested it, I cannot get this to work with polygon data.

Comment: someone must have an idea on how to get a shapely polygon/multipolygon geometry object's coordinates to pass through the timestampedjson api